# Error upgrading from angular 11.2 to 12.2 - styles.css - Error: (0 , _identifier.getUndoPath) is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Like the title says, I'm getting an error building my angular app after using the ng cli to upgrade from angular 11.2 to 12.2:

`styles.css - Error: (0 , _identifier.getUndoPath) is not a function`

I don't have a styles.css file (using styles.scss), nor do I see anywhere that file is referenced.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.0 seems to be the issue. Downgrading it to 12.1.1 fixes the issue for me (while the Angular team fixes the real thing)

Comment: Thanks, went with 12.1.4 and it works again.

Comment: The real answer is to probably just delete package.lock & node_modules/

Comment: deleting package-lock.json and node_modules did not work for me

Comment: I am facing same issue after upgrade angular 12 to 13

Answer (score 4):

for me downgrading the @angular-devkit/build-angular package didn't work, but I looked a little dipper, and I see that webpack is calling this function, so I upgraded the webpack package ("webpack": "^5.50.0"), and this solved the problem.

Comment: This helped me, I had an older webpack version which was causing the problem

Answer (score 4):

For me deleting package.lock & node_modules/* fixed the issue.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21567 | https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21628

Answer (score 1):

my version is v12.2.7, and the solution is `npm i webpack`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if *styles.css* is being imported and used anywhere inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded my angular framework to 12, I struggled with many scss problems. The problem is that the @angular/cli package interprets the packages in the assets folder as external links. I have now downgraded my angular version to 11. If you can manage to interpret your assets directory as , the problem may be solved.

something like this in `angular.json`

```
"assets": [
              ...
              {
                "glob": "**/*.scss",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "ignore": ["**/*.scss"],
                "output": "/assets/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.md",
                "input": "docs",
                "output": "/assets/docs"
              }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me by installing mini-css-extract-plugin in devDependencies.

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21628#issuecomment-909388037